# Do WP7 programs based on silverlight support Lua script in their current version?

Tags: windows-phone-7, lua

I want to add lua script capabilities in WP7 apps as they exist on IOS and Android. Do these apps currently support lua?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately right now you can find only LuaInterface library (which is pretty old though) and which is written and compiled to run under CLR. Silverlight runs under DLR as you may already know. If you need scripting language you can give a chance to F# because you can write F# Silverlight Class library which is compatible with Windows Phone 7 projects.

Comment: Thanks, I wonder to know if I can convert lua scripts to F#...Maybe need huge work...